# is there a shortcut for /dev/stdout like "-" is for /dev/stdin?

Tags: bash

is there a bash shorcut for /dev/stdout like there is "-" for /dev/stdin ?

One of the use cases is to get bash history without line numbers. There is simply no option for that in the history builtin. We can do 'history -w /dev/stdout'.
But that's typing 11 characters (/dev/stdout) and I am looking to shorten it to 1 if possible.

Comment: Usually it's `-`.

Comment: Did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43695212/212107)?

Comment: do we only speak about a redirect? wasn't it similar like 2&1> /file?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, '-' is for stdin, not stdout.

Comment: It's a [convention that is used for both](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16364/2823). It's not a "shortcut", it needs to be implemented by the application.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, in this case we are talking specifically about bash. AFAIK - is exclusively for stdin. Else can you give an example of it being used as stdout in bash?

Comment: There is an example in the linked answers below. But that won't help you since you already tried it and it obviously isn't working. Did you check out the first solution I linked?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, you mean pipeline into cut? That's not as elegant as '-w /dev/stdout' that I used.
Again, there is no problem, as it has been solved in the question  '-w /dev/stdout'. The question is if there are shortcuts to /dev/stdout. And it looks like there aren't.

Comment: No, I linked specifically to the answer by setting the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` environment variable.

Comment: @djdomi, descriptors do not work with history builtin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145912/discussion-between-sergey-guzenkov-and-gerald-schneider).

Comment: @GeraldSchneider do you mean that bash does not have any convention for /dev/stdin or /dev/stdout? Bash does not understand '-' at all. But some third party programs do use this convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-` shortcut that many applications use isn't a special token that's processed by the shell -- it's just a convention implemented in many applications. `cat -` is a common example of this, but `cat` had to manually implement that functionality. From the coreutils `cat` [source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/56e9acb2927874770363462cc6f5d2ee7d2b4c6d/src/cat.c#L673C1-L683C10):

```
bool reading_stdin = STREQ (infile, "-");
if (reading_stdin) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
```

For that reason, we're not going to be able to do something like redirection to `/dev/stdout` with a shortcut like this - redirection and piping is handled at the shell level, while arguments are just passed along to the invoked program. Indeed, `cat -` reads from stdin, but `cat < -` reads from a file called `-`.

That said, it's reasonable that you'd expect this; `-` is often used as a shortcut to redirect output to stdout as well as input from stdin. `ffmpeg` is a notable example off the top of my head that uses such a shortcut, but I'm sure there's plenty.

---

For bash's builtin `history`, however, you might be out of luck -- it doesn't seem to implement any such shortcut. Bash's [history-printing](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814/builtins/history.def#L379C1-L389C3) and [history-writing](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814/lib/readline/histfile.c#L772C1-L774C21) implementations are two separate codepaths, and there doesn't seem to be any way to disable the numbering in the former.

If you never want the numbers in your output, you could perform the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` hack that Gerald Schneider linked to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110119/bash-history-without-line-numbers/43695212#43695212). If you don't like the hack or just want to remove the numbers sometimes, you could save two keystrokes from the original by instead running `history -w /dev/fd/1` (FD 1 is always stdout, I think).